# sorting a vector of userdefined classes based on the string inside the class

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

I have a class. The definition is as follows:

```
using namespace std;

class Token
{
  private:
      string token;
      vector<string> field;

  public:
      void setToken(string s);
      string getToken();    
      void setField(string temp);
      string getField(int i);
      int getsize();
};
```

I now have a vector of these objects. (`vector<Token> myobjs`)
I want to sort this vector based on the `string token`(private variable) in it.
I am using my own compare function to sort that vector

```
bool compare(const vector<Token>&a, const vector<Token>&b)
{
    if(a.getToken() < b.getToken())
    return true;
    return false;
}

vector<Token> delim;
```

Is this not the way to call `sort(delim.begin(), delim.end(), compare)`?

Comment: that if is useless, you can just `return a.getToken() < b.getToken();`

Comment: error: ‘const class std::vector<Token>’ has no member named ‘getToken’ is popping

Comment: @SrinathKattula, this should be in the question itself, not in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare single objects, not vectors:

```
bool compare(const Token & a, const Token & b) {
    return a.getToken() < b.getToken();
}
```

This requires `getToken` to be `const`

```
string getToken() const;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to compare vectors of `token`, you need to compare `token`:

```
bool compare(const Token&a, const Token&b)
{
    return a.getToken() < b.getToken();
}
```

and of course what the other answer already said, `getToken` needs to be marked as `const`:

```
string getToken() const;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Borgleader mentioned you can simplify your predicate a bit, even though it's not the problem here. You actually need to compare `Token`s.

```
bool compare(const Token& a, const Token& b)
{
    return a.getToken() < b.getToken();
}
```

The problem you're having is that the `a` and `b` parameter of your predicate are constant so you cannot call a function member on them that might mutate them.

To fix that you have to mark the getter of your class as constant:

```
class Token
{
  private:
      string token;
      vector<string> field;

  public:
      void setToken(string s);
      string getToken() const;    // edited
      void setField(string temp);
      string getField(int i) const; // edited too
      int getsize() const; // edited too
};
```

BTW, you can also use lambda instead a creating a function. In C++14 you can write:

```
sort(delim.begin(), delim.end(), 
     [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a.getToken() < b.getToken(); }
);
```